# Verantwortung für oder über?

Tags: preposition, single-word-request

In conversation with 2 native German speakers, I said:

> Deshalb verlassen sie sich auf Hilfe, um Zähne zu putzen und die Mundhöhle zu reinigen.

> **Dafür** haben die Krankenpfleger in einem Pflegeheim täglich die Verantwortung.

And they corrected me thusly:

> Deshalb verlassen sie sich auf Hilfe, um Zähne zu putzen und die Mundhöhle zu reinigen.

> **Darüber** haben die Krankenpfleger in einem Pflegeheim täglich die Verantwortung.

Can someone please explain the correction?

I note that Duden provides this example under Verantwortung:

> die Eltern haben, tragen die Verantwortung für ihre Kinder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Dafür** haben (or tragen) die Krankenpfleger in einem Pflegeheim täglich die Verantwortung.

is right. See also the examples in [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Verantwortung).

If you want to have an explanation for the correction, you need to ask the people who told you to use *darüber*. I don't see any reason and for my native German ears *dafür* is perfectly fine, *darüber* sounds strange.